# Do new Italian citizens get to vote for the Senate?

Tags: voting, italy, citizenship

In Italy when you come of age you can't immediately vote for the Senate: you have to wait till you are 25 for that (you can normally vote for pretty much everything else).

If you acquire your citizenship at a later date, do you immediately get to vote for the Senate if you already are above 25 years old, or you have to wait a few years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you acquire the Italian citizenship and you are above 25 years old you can vote for the Senate in the political elections.

Art. 58 of the [Italian Constitution](http://www.quirinale.it/qrnw/statico/costituzione/pdf/costituzione_inglese.pdf) states:

> Senators are elected by universal and direct suffrage by voters who
> are twenty-five years of age.

So, if you are 25 and you have political rights (citizenship), you can vote.